# C++ passing string into C# dll

Tags: c#, c++, string

I have a C++ application calling WORD(name,cpu) function in C# dll via wrapper.cpp and it contain an error. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

> error C2664: 'CsharpDLL::WORD' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'System::String ^'

C++ application

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) void _stdcall WORD(string name, string cpu);

int main()
{
    string name="f";
    string cpu="F";

    WORD(name,cpu);
}
```

wrapper.cpp

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall WORD(string name ,string cpu)
{
    return CsharpDLL::WORD(name,cpu);  // <-- Error here
}
```

C# dll

```
public class CsharpDLL
{
    public static void WORD(string name, string cpu)
    {
    if(cpu=="add")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("aa");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the C++ application is a pure C++ application, or is it *managed* C++ (e.g. C++/CLI or C++/CX)?

Comment: The C++ application is "No Common Language Runtime support" but the wrapper.ccp is "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)"

Comment: Have you tried creating the String like this: `return CsharpDLL::WORD(gcnew String(name), gcnew String(cpu));`?

Comment: You probably should use "const char *" instead of "std::string".

Comment: Pretty sure `const char*` isn't any more implicitly convertible to `System::String^` than `std::string` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a `System::String` from the character array of each `std::string` passed into your wrapper function.

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall WORD(string name ,string cpu)
{
    System::String ^managedName = gcnew System::String(name.c_str());
    System::String ^managedCpu = gcnew System::String(cpu.c_str());

    return CsharpDLL::WORD(managedName, managedCpu);
}
```